# Скроллинг RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

В приложении есть множество картинок, все они не помещаются на экран, я решил сделать скроллинг. И тут возникает небольшая проблема: размещаю scroll vertical на него layout vertical, далее изображения выстраиваются в одну колонну, вопрос очень примитивен,но не как не могу додуматься. Как сделать скроллинг RelativeLayout?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как виджеты связываются в `RelativeLayout` и вообще где разметка? Кому эти картинки и что могут сказать о вашей проблеме, вы не подумали? - они бесполезны.

Comment: Если вам надо динамический список, то используйте ListView или RecyclerView. Если надо просто поместить кучу статических картинок на экран, то используйте контейнер ScrollView

Comment: Был баг студии, Relative не помещался на scroll, после перезапуска все ок. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну возьмите ваш `RelativeLayout` с изображениями, и положите в `ScrollView` вместо `LinearLayout`. Любой `ViewGroup` может быть контейнером в `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Если таких вот картинок у вас будет много, вы серьёзно рискуете получить OutOfMemory, или хотя бы тормоза на слабых девайсах. Для этой цели рекомендовал бы вам всё-таки использовать ListView (а ещё лучше RecyclerView), независимо от того, статический у вас набор данных или динамический. Так вы сможете реализовать паттерн ViewHolder, позволяющий сэкономить ресурсы устройства.